# Cannot access Entity Framework Core 7.0 compiled model when configuring builder, service

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-7.0

In my ASP.NET Core 7.0 I built an Entity Framework Core compiled model. In the `program.cs`, I was unable to access the instance of the model.

Normally in `program.cs` I do the following:

```
.AddDbContextPool<CondoDBContext>(s => s.UseSqlServer(connection), int.Parse(sqlpool))
```

But for a compiled model how do I access the instance of the compiled model.

Any help would be appreciated.